# Accessing struct fields from emscripten

Tags: javascript, emscripten

Given the following code:

```
typedef struct {
  int foo;
} Bar;

Bar test() { Bar result = { .foo = 2 }; return result; }
```

and assuming that `test()` can be accessed from JavaScript, how would I convert the struct to a JavaScript object or otherwise be able to use the return value such that (in JavaScript) `myJavascriptObject.foo == 2` will return true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is doing things as in java:

```
Bar createBar(int foo) {
  Bar result = { .foo = foo };
  return result;
}

int getFoo(Bar in) { return in.foo; }
```

Ugly, adds boilerplate, and requires more stuff be exported, but it works.