# Can't export gl functions when compiling with emscripten

Tags: c++, emscripten

I am trying to compile some c++ code using emscripten to html to run on a browser.

However, when I try to compile with emcc main.cpp -o main.html I get the error:
`error: undefined symbol: glColor3f (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)` that appears for all gl functions I am using.

I tried exporting the functions using `emcc main.cpp -o main.html -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=”[‘_glColor3f’]”` however that causes the error: `emcc: error: undefined exported function: "‘_glColor3f’" [-Wundefined] [-Werror]`

I tried creating a header file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
#endif
        void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE _glColor3f(GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue);
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }

#endif
```

But that still causes the same error. I am unsure how to define these functions or what I should do to have the code compile.

Comment: You probably just need to emulate a different opengl version. Try compiling with `-s FULL_ES2=1` or `-s FULL_ES3=1`

Comment: Also note the difference between a function *definition* and *declaration*. A *definition* is when you add source code to a function: `void foo() { /* Implementation goes here */ }`. *declaration* is saying "somewhere in the whole wide world there exists a function with this signature": `void foo();` Adding headers (usually) only fixes declaration problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling for such a long time. You can try `-s EXPORT_ALL=1` described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33208675/4441984).